# Create Sub-group weights in R

Tags: r, frequency

I currently have the following table/csv in R:

```
Name    Value   Sector  Date
Company1    100 Financials  3/31/2015
Company2    100 Energy  3/31/2015
Company3    100 Healthcare  3/31/2015
Company4    100 Financials  3/31/2015
Company5    100 Energy  3/31/2015
Company6    100 Healthcare  3/31/2015
Company1    100 Financials  6/30/2015
Company2    200 Energy  6/30/2015
Company3    200 Healthcare  6/30/2015
Company4    200 Financials  6/30/2015
Company5    200 Energy  6/30/2015
```

What I want to create is for each quarter end date, the weights for each Sector based on Value.

I have been using:

```
cdata <- ddply(Test.Exposure, c("Date", "Sector"), summarise,
               Sumx1 = sum(Value))
```

This gives me:

```
            Date     Sector Sumx1
1      3/31/2015     Energy   200
2      3/31/2015 Financials   200
3      3/31/2015 Healthcare   200
4      6/30/2015     Energy   400
5      6/30/2015 Financials   300
6      6/30/2015 Healthcare   400
```

1) Is there a way to get `%` of a sum?

2) Is it possible to show only one line for each quarter end date, and have each sector in one column like this:

```
         Financials Energy  Healthcare
3/31/2015   33,33%  33,33%  33,33%
6/30/2015   ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` following by `rowSums`:

```
a <- xtabs(Sumx1~Date+Sector, d)

#           Sector
#Date        Energy Financials Healthcare
#  3/31/2015    200        200        200
#  6/30/2015    400        300        400

round(a/rowSums(a)*100, 2)

#           Sector
#Date        Energy Financials Healthcare
#  3/31/2015  33.33      33.33      33.33
#  6/30/2015  36.36      27.27      36.36
```

**data**

```
d <- read.table(text="            Date     Sector Sumx1
1      3/31/2015     Energy   200
2      3/31/2015 Financials   200
3      3/31/2015 Healthcare   200
4      6/30/2015     Energy   400
5      6/30/2015 Financials   300
6      6/30/2015 Healthcare   400", header=T)
```

Comment: Thank you @m0h3n this works just fine!

My final code is:

cdata <- ddply(Test.Exposure, c("Valuation.Date", "Sector"), summarise,
               Sumx1 = sum(Market.Value))

a <- xtabs(Sumx1~Valuation.Date+Sector, cdata)

round(a/rowSums(a)*100, 2)

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Test.Exposure %>% 
    group_by(Date, Sector) %>% 
    summarise(Sumx1 = sum(Value)) %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>%
    mutate(Sumx1 = round(100*Sumx1/sum(Sumx1),2)) %>% 
    spread(Sector, Sumx1)
#       Date Energy Financials Healthcare
#      <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    
#1 3/31/2015  33.33      33.33      33.33
#2 6/30/2015  36.36      27.27      36.36
```

Comment: In my original data the numbers in the Value column are of the type "100,125,125"  io 100 125 125.
So R reads those as character and wont let me do : summarise(Sumx1 = sum(Value)) 

I try various as.numeric(as.character(Value) but this wont work. Any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: @lapioche75  If the `ddply` you showed in your post works for you in that dataset, the `dplyr` option should also work.  Or is it a different question?

Comment: @lapioche75  Perhaps you need to split it up. `library(tidyr); separate_rows(Test.Exposure, Value, convert = TRUE) %>% group_by(Date, Sector) %>% summarise(Sum1 = sum(Value))` and then do the rest